# Infinite series with $2$ positive and $2$ negative terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Finding value  of $$1+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{17}-\frac{1}{19}-\frac{1}{23}+\cdots$$

Try: I have solved in using Integration

But i am trying to solver it without using integration

Witting above series as $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n\bigg[\frac{1}{6n+1}+\frac{1}{6n+5}\bigg]$$

Now i am trying to solve it using euler reflection formula

Could not find any clue

could some help me to solve it

Comment: Would writing it as $1+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^{n}\bigg[\frac{1}{6n+1}-\frac{1}{6n-1}\bigg]$ help?

Comment: I would try to perform multisection on the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1-x)$, to obtain closed form of the series $$\sum \frac{x^{6n+1}}{6n+1}$$, and then plug in a suitable value of $x$.

Comment: Is there anything I could improve which prevents you right now from accepting my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $$1+\frac15-\frac17-\frac1{11}+\frac1{13}+\frac1{17}-\frac1{19}-\frac1{23}+\cdots=\frac{\pi}3$$

Utilizing the observation done by *Mohammad Zuhair Khan* we can explicitly write down the series as

$$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left[\frac1{6n+1}-\frac1{6n-1}\right]=1-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{36n^2-1}$$

The latter form can be rewritten such that we can apply a [sum identity of the cosecant function](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Csc/06/ShowAll.html). To be precise we will use the formula

> $$\pi\csc(\pi z)=z\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{z^2-n^2}=\frac1z-2z\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2-z^2}$$

Thus, lets rewrite the given series in the following way

$$\begin{align}
1-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{36n^2-1}&=1+\frac16\left[-2\frac16\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2-\left(\frac16\right)^2}\right]\\
&=1+\frac16\left[\pi\csc\left(\frac\pi6\right)-6\right]\\
&=\frac\pi6\csc\left(\frac\pi6\right)
\end{align}$$

> $$\therefore~1-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{36n^2-1}=\frac\pi3$$

Comment: Nice solution mrtaurho.

Comment: @DXT Thank you! Glad to help.